# .each function on Jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I'm coding something that i want different objects to rotate following the mouse movement.

The code is kind of slowing down the page so I'm trying to optimize it.

Heres the original code where it calls the function:

```
var arrow1 = $('#arrowD1');
var arrow2 = $('#arrowD2');
var arrow3 = $('#arrowD3');
var arrow4 = $('#arrowD4');

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow1);
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow2);
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow3);
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow4);
});
```

instead of calling the function for each element, I just want to have one function for all the elements with the same class:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
  $('.arrow-designers').each(rotateOnMouse(e, this));
});
```

[Updated Codepen]
http://codepen.io/thalesribeiro/pen/KaRmLB

Is there anything I'm missing in the syntax?

Cheers,
T

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function once and passing in the result to `each`, which isn't going to work. Instead:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.arrow-designers').each(function(arrow) {
    rotateOnMouse(e, arrow));
  });
});
```

Like a lot of iterator functions in jQuery and Lodash/Underscore you need to pass `each` a function which is evaluated for each element. There's a big difference between `f(this)` and `function() { f(this) }`.

Comment: Now it makes more sense to me how to do the syntax with functions, although the code is still not working for me. I added my codepen so you can see how it works.

Comment: When writing JavaScript **always** keep your error console open. I get " pw.offset is not a function." with your code.